# How to Send Headers in Google Drive Rest Api Post Request?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, retrofit

**I am trying to upload an image to Google Drive but not sure how to set headers when sending POST request in Google Drive Rest Api using Multipart.**

**According to the documentation I need to set Four Headers written below**

(a) Metadata part: Must come first, and must have a Content-Type header set to application/json; charset=UTF-8. Add the file's metadata to this part in JSON format.

(b) Media part: Must come second, and must have a Content-Type header, which may have any MIME type. Add the file's data to this part.

**Also I need to set Top Level HTTP Headers as well:**

(c) Content-Type: Set to multipart/related, and include the boundary string you're using to identify the different parts of the request. For example: Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz

(d) Content-Length: Set to the total number of bytes in the request body.

How do I find the Content Length here?

```
public interface GDriveWebService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("upload")

    Call<GoogleDriveFileHolder> uploadFile(@Part("description") RequestBody description, @Part MultipartBody.Part content);


}
```

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution. If you find it please share it